# python: the speed of sum

Tags: python, performance

I know the fastest way to sum a list of number is use the built in function `sum`. Using a `for` loop could be a slower way to do the sum than using `reduce`. However when I try it, it is not true. Can someone explain this result?

```
import time, random, operator

sample = [random.randrange(10000) for _ in range(1000000)]

def use_for(l):
    acc = 0
    for n in l:
        acc += n
    print acc

def use_lambda(l):
    print reduce(operator.add, l)

print time.time()
use_for(l)
print time.time()
use_lambda(l)
print time.time()
```

the time I get:

```
1479671513.04
4998734199
1479671513.07
4998734199
1479671513.13
```

Comment: Running on a single computer only once isn't really a good benchmark

Comment: For anybody wondering, the actual times were `.03` seconds for the for loop, and `.06` seconds for the reduce method.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, `time.time()` could jump back and forth a little bit, while `time.monotonic` cannot.

Comment: Why did you title your question "The speed of sum" when you are asking about the speed of `reduce`?

Comment: You should also try for `sum(l)`

Answer (score 5):

Let me show you how to do this more systematically.  First, you should use the `timeit` module for benchmarking.  It's a little awkward to use correctly but it is significantly more accurate.  Second, make absolutely certain you are not doing any work *other* than the work you care about benchmarking within the test.  In particular, you should not print out anything in the functions under test, because printing things is expensive.  Third, you should test each candidate function over a *range of lengths* and then graph the result.  Fourth, you don't need to go up to a million numbers to get useful results.

```
import csv
import operator
import random
import sys
from functools import partial, reduce
from timeit import timeit

lengths = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000]

samples = [ [random.randrange(10000) for i in range(n)]
            for n in lengths ]

def use_for(l):
    acc = 0
    for n in l: acc += n
    return acc

def use_reduce(l):
    return reduce(operator.add, l)

def use_sum(l):
    return sum(l)

def main():
    with sys.stdout as ofp:
        wr = csv.writer(ofp, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        wr.writerow(('len','for loop','reduce','sum'))

        for length, sample in zip(lengths, samples):
            t_for = timeit(partial(use_for, sample), number=1000)
            t_red = timeit(partial(use_reduce, sample), number=1000)
            t_sum = timeit(partial(use_sum, sample), number=1000)
            wr.writerow((length, t_for, t_red, t_sum))

main()
```

We run this test program, and then we plot the output.  You didn't say whether you were using Python 2 or 3, so I wrote the above to work with either, and I tested it both ways.  **[EDIT:** And since another answer mentioned it, I've now tested PyPy as well.**]** Don't worry about the details of what I'm doing to make plots - [`ggplot`](http://ggplot2.org/) is well worth learning, but it, and the R language it's embedded in, can be pretty darn cryptic.

```
$ python2 sumbench.py > sumbench-2.csv
$ python3 sumbench.py > sumbench-3.csv
$ pypy    sumbench.py > sumbench-P.csv
$ R --quiet
> suppressPackageStartupMessages({ library(reshape2); library(ggplot2); })
> data2 <- melt(read.csv('sumbench-2.csv'), id.var='len')
> data3 <- melt(read.csv('sumbench-3.csv'), id.var='len')
> dataP <- melt(read.csv('sumbench-P.csv'), id.var='len')
> data2$interp <- ordered('CPython 2', levels=c('CPython 2','CPython 3','PyPy'))
> data3$interp <- ordered('CPython 3', levels=c('CPython 2','CPython 3','PyPy'))
> dataP$interp <- ordered('PyPy',      levels=c('CPython 2','CPython 3','PyPy'))
> data <- rbind(data2, data3, dataP)
> colnames(data) <- c("Input length", "Algorithm", "Time (ms)", "Interpreter")
> ggplot(data, aes(x=`Input length`, y=`Time (ms)`,
                   colour=`Algorithm`, linetype=`Algorithm`)) +
      facet_grid(.~`Interpreter`) + geom_line() +
      theme_grey(base_size=9) +
      theme(legend.position=c(0.01,0.98), legend.justification=c(0,1))
```

[image: Linear plot of all three algorithms' performance on three different Python interpreters]

Which pretty clearly demonstrates that using `reduce` is indeed slower than the `for` loop, but `sum` is much faster than either.  It also clearly demonstrates that CPython 3.5 is slower at this than 2.7, which is sad but expected.  PyPy is not only a solid 5x faster than either of them, but all three algorithms perform equally well! That's what happens when you throw a genuine optimizing compiler at this sort of code.  (PyPy is faster than CPython's `sum()` intrinsic because it can figure out that all the elements of the array are numeric and slice out a bunch of per-element overhead.  The `sum` method of a NumPy array would probably be as fast or faster than PyPy.)

It's often good to plot data like this on a log-log scale - this is also why I picked the lengths I did:

```
> last_plot() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: Same plot as above but on a log-log scale.]

See how they've all got roughly the same slope now?  That means the [*asymptotic complexity*](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2013sp/supplemental/lectures/lec19-asymp/review.html) of all three techniques is the same, O(n), just different constant factors.  Asymptotic complexity is important because it lets you predict how long bigger inputs will take.  In this case, we could just extend the three lines out to a million on the x-axis if we wanted to know how long they would take for your original test case.  With a different big-O we'd see curves, and we'd need to extrapolate them differently.

We can also see that sum() has a bend in its curve, which was completely invisible on the linear plot; that means there  might be some special casing of short lists in the implementation.  And it's also clearer that `reduce` has very nearly the same performance as the hand-written `for` loop in 2 but not 3; `reduce` is no longer a built-in function in 3, but it's still implemented in compiled code, so I don't have an explanation for this.
And we can see that PyPy is dramatically *slower* at the beginning, in an unpredictable way: that's because the cost of just-in-time compilation of the functions being benchmarked has been ascribed to the early calls.  I could add a "warm-up" step to the benchmark and make that go away, but it's a good thing to know about.

On the other hand, the fact that CPython 3 is significantly slower than CPython 2 is much harder to see on the log-log plot.

Comment: This is great. Micro side note: with `reduce` you can just do `from functools import reduce` in Python 2 and Python 3 since in Python 2 it is linked back to the built-in

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions. It is awesome

Answer (score 2):

I get dramatically different timings for [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

You might want to use `timeit` as a better way to time small bits of code. Here is an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import operator
from functools import reduce

def f1(l):
    return sum(l)

def f2(l):
    return reduce(operator.add, l)

def f3(l):
    s=0
    for e in l:
        s+=e
    return s    

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit 
    import random  
    l=[random.randrange(10000) for _ in range(1000000)] 
    for f in (f1, f2, f3):
        print("   ",f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(l)", setup="from __main__ import f, l", number=100) )
```

Python3 prints:

```
f1 0.7481771620000472
f2 6.92161642699989
f3 5.201012654999886
```

Python2 prints:

```
f1 0.554444074631
f2 4.81940102577
f3 3.65543603897
```

PyPy:

```
f1 0.108825922012
f2 0.112055063248
f3 0.105736970901
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading your question the first thing that came to my mind:

> Using a for loop could be a slower way to do the sum than using reduce

Is this based on some documentation or data or just an assumption? I read around a little, and it looks like it is just an assumption.

Based on python document on [functional programming](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html)

> Functional design may seem like an odd constraint to work under. Why should you avoid objects and side effects? There are theoretical and practical advantages to the functional style:
>
> - Formal provability.
> - Modularity.
> - Composability.
> - Ease of debugging and testing.

Speed doesn't seem to be an advantage. If anything, I think because of the overhead of calling a function it will be slow (your empirical data supports this).

Also, `sum` is faster as it is implemented in `c`

Comment: OP asked why his `reduce` call is slower and I explained that his assumption that `reduce` should be faster is incorrect. I do not see why my answer is not helpful. If you are downvoting, please explain.